# Variable to be populated asynchronously only in special case

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

Inside a huge controller, I'm relying on data from a database. This data is retrieved using `resolve` within the state definition.
However, in rare and special cases, there is no data from the main database and I have to use default data from another database (which takes some time to load). Of course, by no means, the default data should be loaded each time, but just in those rare cases, it is needed. So, also loading the default data using `resolve` in the state definition is not on option, I think.

So, I have to use a simple if-else-statement, retrieving the default data only if the "normal" data fetched by `resolve` was not successfully loaded. The default data is then retrieved with a service function with a callback. My current code looks like such:

```
if (dataLoadedViaResolve.success){
    $scope.myMainVariable = dataLoadedViaResolve;
} else {
    myService.getDefaults(function(data){
        $scope.myMainVariable = data;
    });
}

// Do a lot of things with $scope.myMainVariable in hundreds of lines of code
```

Of course, this doesn't work, because I'm running into trouble with asynchronous behavior. I was advised to use a promise here, but after all the promise would provide me just with another kind of callback function to put the code the be executed inside the `else` statement into. However, that would mean refactoring the whole controller (which would get me in some trouble, I guess).

Is the an elegant way to make the execution of the script wait till `$scope.myMainVariable` is being populated inside the `else` statement and then afterwards use `$scope.myMainVariable` outside the `else` statement?

Comment: can you provide more code snippet of your entire function in the controller? not just the if-else condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True. The only option you have to use a promise. You can simply achieve it like this:

```
$scope.getMyMainVar = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var myMainVariable;

    if (dataLoadedViaResolve.success) {
        defer.resolve({myMainVariable: dataLoadedViaResolve});
    } else {
        myService.getDefaults(function(data) {
            defer.resolve({myMainVariable: data});
        });
    }

    return defer.promise;
};
```

Now, inside your controller or anywhere, you can write like this:

```
$scope.getMyMainVar().then(function(data) {
     $scope.myMainVariable = myMainVariable;
     // Do a lot of things with $scope.myMainVariable in hundreds of lines of code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the `dataLoadedViaResolve` in a [`$q.when()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when), this will make `$scope.myMainVariable` a promise, then you could do:

```
$scope.myMainVariable
    .then(function(data) {
        // Do something with your data
    }
);
```

Comment: Well, what I meant is: Wrapping all "Do something in my data" functionality inside another pair of curly brackets is something I'd like to avoid. And your solution would require exactly this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @cis Unless you always want to resolve the default data you can't do much else besides using a promise

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
if(dataLoadedViaResolve.success){
  $scope.myMainVariable = dataLoadedViaResolve;
 }

else {
  myService.getDefaults().then(function(data){
    $scope.myMainVariable = data;
 });
}
```

Comment: What would that change? `$scope.myMainVariable` is already correctly set inside callback function inside the `else`  statement, but outside of it, I get "undefined". Same is true for using promise and $q.defer.